# 'If my beads are parted, come right in.'

Tags: sentence-meaning

What does "If my beads are parted, come right in." mean? This sentence is said by a professor to Marge.

> Prof.  : Marge, I hope I'll be seeing you tomorrow during office hours.
>
> Marge  : Uh, 3:00 to 5:00, right ?
>
> Prof. : If my beads are parted, come right in.
>
> Marge : I will !

The Simpsons Episode 11,season 19

Comment: This refers to a bead curtain, I suppose.  "Bead are parted" if the strands of beads are held to each side by some means leaving an opening.

Comment: It's the bead curtain equivalent of 'if my door is open'.

Comment: I was about to answer this question, but the comments answer cover what I was about to write.

Answer (score 2):

This is talking about **a bead curtain**

It is the equivalent of a door, or curtains, and means

> If my door is open, come right in

Where in this case the "door" is actually a curtain. Come right in means "don't knock or ask permission, just enter when you arrive"

"Parted" refers to the fact that curtains are often held open by a string or similar, separating them to each side of the doorway.

This is a bead curtain:

[image: A bead curtain]